# Integration latency on API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, latency

Recently my system have a problem like this, suddenly integration latency from API Gateway is higher than usual, especially at night.
[image]

Check Logs Insight, I saw these happened.

[image]

Somehow, for some request, it took 7s to finish integration.  At first I think this problem is from lambda and I also checked it, but seems like it's not.

[image: enter image description her]

Lambda took only more than 1s (higher than normal a little) to finish execute and it also started right after integration completed.

Please have anyone solved these kind of problem before ? can you plaease give me some advice ?